# Page Not Found error with 301 Permanent Redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have following codes for my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Redirect Old Page to New Page
Redirect 301 /2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html http://domainname.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/

Header unset ETag  
FileETag None

<filesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
Header set Expires "Sun, 23 October 2011 20:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css|css.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js|js.gz)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
```

but when i came to the this post via google search then i get the `PAGE NOT FOUND` error. I tested this code in my localhost that working file but not on the real server can anyone tell me where is the exact problem??

Comment: Redirect 301 /2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html http://domainname.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/

Comment: @Akam getting 500 internal server error.

Comment: did you removed this 'http:// domainname.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/'? and are you sure that this path also exists (/2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html)?

Comment: @Akam yes ofcause, take a look on the link http://webomnizz.com/blog/2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html and the changed link http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/

Comment: @Akam i have used Redirect 301 /2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html webomnizz.com/blog/jquery/ajax-based-instant-image-upload/ that provide me the 500 internal server error

Comment: Redirect 301 /2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html only

Comment: @Akam still getting 500 internal server error, and how this code determine that where he has to redirect? cause i have around 30 pages which i have to redirect with 301

Comment: you should check both URL exist and then redirect older to the new

Comment: @Akam it would be great if you show some example?

Comment: simply 'Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html' please remove redirect line just for testing that the error is  form it or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24009/discussion-between-akam-and-webomnizz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Blog to the old URL:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html http://webomnizz.com/blog/jquery
```